# Apache mod_rewrite rule doesn't work for different pages

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a rewrite rule on apache2 in the .htaccess file that is working fine for the posts.php page.

```
mysite.com/post.php?id_name=this-is-the-title-of-my-site
```

becomes

```
mysite.com/this-is-the-title-of-my-site
```

I want to use the same rule for the cats.php page so that

```
mysite.com/cats.php?cat_label=articles
```

becomes

```
mysite.com/articles
```

I have used the same rule and changed the file name and the parameters but the rule for the cats.php page seems to fail and be overridden by the posts.php rule

I would prefer not to but I don't mind changing the structure to become

```
mysite.com/cats/articles
```

This is the .htaccess file that I am using at the moment

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id_name=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cats.php?cat_label=$1 [L,QSA]
```

All help is truly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag `[L]` means "Last", as in, when that rule is matched, it is the last rewrite rule tested.  You need a way to distinguish the two types of redirects.  Here's two ways you might do that:

**(1) Have dashes in all of your post names, but not in your categories, so both of your given examples work as given:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)$ cats.php?cat_label=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**(2) Add a directory for the categories so that there isn't any magical character stuff going on, which can lead to mistakes.**  You already confronted this possibility above.  Here's how it would look:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*)$ cats.php?cat_label=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In both cases, we match the more specific versions first, flagging them as `[L]`ast.  Then we have the broad, catchall at the end.